# Not getting why my routing is not working in Angular6

Tags: angular6, angular-routing, routeparams

I am not seeing why my item level route is not getting hit.  So I have looked up the Angular site on routing here: https://angular.io/guide/router.  I have a main routing setup like this:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'Login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/Login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'Money',
    //Could this be wrong path and nothing is telling me?
    loadChildren: '../Modules/Money/money.module#MoneyModule',
    //canLoad: [LoginGuard]
  },
  { path: '**',  component: PageNotFoundComponent },
]
//, { enableTracing: true } 
)
],
exports: [ RouterModule ],
providers: [LoginGuard, AuthService]
})
```

I have a 'Module' for my Money like so.  I tried to setup the '' to inherit the direct from the parent route but it never works so that may be part of the problem as well.

```
  RouterModule.forChild(
  [
    // { path: '', component: MoneyListingsComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
    { path: 'Money', component: MoneyListingsComponent },
    { path: 'Money:id', component: MoneyEntryComponent }
  ])
```

And then I have an implementation in the html like so:

```
<div id="moneyEntryArea">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  <div *ngFor="let tran of transactions">
    <div>ID: 
      <a [routerLink]="['/Money', tran.transactionID]">{{tran.transactionID}}</a>
      Amount: {{tran.amount}} 
      Desc:{{tran.transactionDesc}} 
      Running Total:{{tran.runningTotal}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically my list comes up just fine but when I click on a 'transaction's' id it gets swallowed up with an error like:

```
 "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
 at Array.map (<anonymous>)
 at webpackAsyncContext (http://localhost:4200/main.js:2710:34)
 at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59394:82)
at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59386:60)
at RouterConfigLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:122028:82)
at RouterConfigLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.RouterConfigLoader.load (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:122016:35)
at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120288:47)
at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:132985:27)
at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:132975:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:127446:18)"
```

I feel like I am missing something simple like I need to inject another directive somewhere but am getting lost in the levels.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was essentially multiple problems:

1. When you lazy load routes with the '(location)#Module' you need to ensure that the further downstream components are set up right.  EG: path: "/Money" that leads to a new module that implements RouterModule.ForChildren() has to have those routes assume the parent's path.  So '' becomes 'Money'.
2. In Angular it appears that doing the routelink="(route)" is not the same as [routeLink]="['/(route)']".  I was doing the latter and it was causing problems.
3. When you have a lazy loaded route you may have problems with loading the 'BrowserModule' again.  You need to load the 'CommonModule' in lazy loaded modules further down the tree.
4. I was using Angular Material so those had to be downloaded for the modules being loaded again.

Now it works fine.